# ORDER BY with different WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is illustrated scenario for my problem.

```
SELECT field
FROM myTable
WHERE field1 = 'abc' AND filed2 = 'xyz' AND field3 = 'pqr'
ORDER BY field4 ASC
```

This query give me result as:

```
result1
result2
result3
```

Now if I run following query, then

```
SELECT field
FROM myTable
WHERE field1 = 'xxx' AND field2 = 'xyz'
ORDER BY field4 ASC

result2
result3
result1
```

So, basically both query give same results but with different order. But I want result from first query with second query's `ORDER BY`. See both have different condition on `field1`. Everything else is same.

Comment: A table has _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Does multiple rows have the same result values?

Comment: Add sample table data as well, giving the specified result.

Comment: @jophab: no. Unique value.

Comment: Select the value of field4 also in both queries and then compare

Comment: what you are saying does not match the example because the second query has different conditions than the first one, therefore it is not clear what you are after. In other words, if you get the same results is because of the example and not general

Comment: Can you provide the data, as well as the schema, so that we can make sense of your queries? Otherwise, everyone is wasting their time with guesses.

Comment: The only way that the order will be different, is if the different `WHERE` clauses give rise to different result sets. And, if that is the case, then exactly what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this.

2 query return different rows (the first with field1 = 'abc', the second with 'xxx'), so why should these 2 result sets correlate?

Here is an example:

```
declare @myTable table (field varchar(100), 
                        field1 varchar(100), 
                        field2 varchar(100), 
                        field3 varchar(100), 
                        field4 int);

insert into @myTable (field, field1, field2, field3, field4)
values  ('result1', 'abc', 'xyz', 'pqr',1),
('result2', 'abc', 'xyz', 'pqr',2),
('result3', 'abc', 'xyz', 'pqr',3);

insert into @myTable (field, field1, field2, field4)
values
('result2', 'xxx', 'xyz',1),
('result3', 'xxx', 'xyz',2),
('result1', 'xxx', 'xyz',3);


SELECT field
FROM @myTable
WHERE field1 = 'abc' AND field2 = 'xyz' AND field3 = 'pqr'
ORDER BY field4 ASC

--result1
--result2
--result3

SELECT field
FROM @myTable
WHERE field1 = 'xxx' AND field2 = 'xyz'
ORDER BY field4 ASC

--result2
--result3
--result1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a sub query of the 2nd statement into the 1st like below and order on that.

```
SELECT t1.field, 
(SELECT top 1 t2.field4
    FROM myTable t2
    WHERE t2.field1 = 'xxx' AND t2.field2 = 'xyz'
    AND t2.field = t1.field) as orderField
FROM myTable t1
WHERE t1.field1 = 'abc' AND t1.filed2 = 'xyz' AND t1.field3 = 'pqr'
ORDER BY orderField ASC
```